# apply jquery selector to object corresponding to hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For some reason `.add` on the last line doesn't work as expected, all the `:first-child` in the document are modified, I want only the `:first-child` from the hovered object to be modified. I tried everything I could think of, have no idea what the problem is.

```
jQuery.fn.img=function(background,param,repeat)
    { $(this).css('background-image','url(/static/img/'+background+'.png')
             .css('background-repeat',repeat)
             .css('background-position',param+' top');}

$('#sliding-door li').hover(function(e)
{$(this).img('b1_middle_focus','left','repeat-x');
 $(this).add(':first-child span').img('b1_left_focus','left','no-repeat');},
```

The html:

```
<ul>
          <li><a href="/href1"><span><span>Something</span></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/href2"><span><span>Another thing</span></span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `.add()`? Don't you mean `.find()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I see what you're trying to do now. If you still need the hover function to apply on all the `li`s, while testing for the first child for just one subroutine, you can use an if statement:

```
$('#sliding-door li').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).img('b1_middle_focus','left','repeat-x');

    if ($(this).is(':first-child')) {
        $(this).find('span').img('b1_left_focus','left','no-repeat');
    }
}, ...);
```

---

**Old answer, ignore**

If you're looking for the `span` in the first child of `$(this)`, you meant to use `$(this).find()` rather than `$(this).add()`:

```
$(this).find(':first-child span').img('b1_left_focus','left','no-repeat');
```

`.add()` adds all the elements matched by the `:first-child span` selector on a document level to the `$(this)` object, which isn't quite what you expect it to do. See the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/add

Comment: actually it's no good, i want it to test if the hovered object is the first child, not select the first child after that

Comment: That's different from what you asked. Can I see your HTML?

Comment: here's an example how the two work, i would like the second one to behave like the first one http://pastebin.com/hCB1vWSa

Comment: I think I'll test test the hover separately for the first and other stuff